# need help setting up ruby on rails javascript runtime environment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, archlinux

I'm having trouble setting up ruby on rails on my machine.  I've been following the book "Agile Web Development with Rails" and up until now everything has been going fine.

The problem I'm having is that when I type

```
rails server
```

I get the following error:

```
/home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:50:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
from /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
from /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.3.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler.rb:118:in `require'
from /home/myname/Programming/Learning/Learning_Rails/demo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /home/myname/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

It's saying that it can't find a javascript runtime environment.  I went to the website that the error message recommended and I did some googling and I read that execjs would be a good choice to install.  I installed execjs with the following commands:

```
sudo gem install execjs
sudo gem update
```

When I run 'gem list' I get the following output:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.2)
actionpack (3.2.2)
activemodel (3.2.2)
activerecord (3.2.2)
activeresource (3.2.2)
activesupport (3.2.2)
arel (3.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.0)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.2.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.3.0 ruby)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.3)
jquery-rails (2.0.1)
json (1.6.5, 1.5.4)
mail (2.4.3)
mime-types (1.17.2)
minitest (2.11.3, 2.5.1)
multi_json (1.1.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.2)
railties (3.2.2)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12, 3.9.4)
sass (3.1.15)
sass-rails (3.2.4)
sprockets (2.3.1, 2.1.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.5)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.32)
uglifier (1.2.3)
```

From the output above it looks to me like execjs is installed.  What's going on here and why am I getting this error?

If it's helpful at all,

My OS is Arch Linux.

ruby -v:  ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-linux]

rails -v: Rails 3.2.2

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your Gemfile should contain BOTH of the following lines:

```
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
```

Then run `bundle install` and try again.

Answer (score 5):

If you will add therubyracer gem , may be your problem woould be solved

Code

```
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'execjs'
```

then just do a `bundle install`

Comment: I tried running the command gem 'therubyracer' but I got an error saying that therubyracer is an unknown command.  The same thing happens if I run gem 'execjs'.  Did I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a runtime like rubyracer.
Try

```
sudo gem install therubyracer
```

Comment: I tried that and this was the result:
    `$ bundle install execjs
    "install" was called incorrectly. Call as "bundle install".`

Comment: Edited to specify a js runtime.

Comment: rubyracer doesn't appear in gem list output. Are you sure it's installed?

Comment: Well, I ran sudo gem install therubyracer.  It looked like it was installing and overall it took about 5 minutes.  There weren't any error messages while it was installing and afterwards I ran sudo gem update.  Did I miss a step?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Pacman packet manager you should use:

```
# pacman -S nodejs
```

or

```
$ sudo pacman -S nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd installed Node.js before Rails. Now its using Node.js as the javascript runtime by itself.

```
JavaScript Runtime  Node.js (V8)
```